# how to fuzz program using libfuzzer?

Tags: llvm, clang++, fuzzing, libfuzzer

command:clang++ fuzz_target.cpp -o fuzz_target -fsanitize=fuzzer -lFuzzer
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'Fuzzer.lib'
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1181 (use -v to see invocation)
What is this error.How to resolve this

I tried to compile a c++ program with the command.But i encounter this error.

Comment: It means the `Fuzzer.lib` file is not in any of your library paths.

Comment: In addition to the `-l` option you might need `-Lwhere_to_find_it`.